# how to load a picture to array by pixels?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, image

I have an absolutely white picture. And i declare it like that.

```
NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ball.png"]];
self.view=[UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

And somewhere i have one black pixel. How can i load it to array. Which has

> 0

is like a white color and

> 1

is a black color? I need to read it to array. How to get it back to the screen. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you really need to do that? Or is that a proposed solution for some other problem?

Comment: yeah...it is a proposed solution for other problem. I don't understand hot to read it to array.

Comment: Are you sure `self.view` is an `UIImage`?

Comment: You might be better to ask about the other problem and see if there is a better / simpler solution...